# jQuery .live() to attach Omniture click tracking handlers?

Tags: analytics, jquery, adobe-analytics

We are trying to rid our site of what is often 100s of inline onclick="" handlers on elements. The majority of these are Omniture click tracking functions attached via the onclick attribute.

Since they are all the same code, I want to simply bind a single handler to the document, using jQuery's .live() function. Then we'd update the links/buttons/elements we want tracked to have a unique marker like class="trackable". We'd have the handler registered something like as follows (consider this pseudocode):

```
$('.trackable').live('click', function(e) { 
  trackClick();
};
```

Obviously we'd need some params in there, and we'd deduce those from the event source object, maybe via data-attributes or something.

My concern is mainly with reliability. From my reading, live() handlers don't get interrupted - the event should bubble up and be handled before the browser unloads the page, for instance. I'm not sure of that, though. I also have some concerns about browser compatibility.

Does anyone have any experience with live() event binding and Omniture (or Google Analytics)?

Comment: Here is a full post about link tracking in Omniture using jQuery http://www.keystonesolutions.com/community/2011/07/731/

Comment: The approach in the Keystone article suffers from a common problem: tracking is only applied to links that were present when the track-binding function was invoked. The obvious ideal is to use a delegated event handler (like the OP suggests) that tracks all desired links. The issue is that it's less clear how to provide the 500ms delay that Omniture's s.tl() method introduces to allow the tracking call to complete before the browser navigates away. The first parameter of s.tl() seems relevant, but existing documentation is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I feel like it's pretty crude, but I think it works.

```
// attach omniture tracking to links within search results
jQuery('.app1 .app1-searchresults').on('click', '.app1-entry a', function(event) {
    var jLink = jQuery(event.target);

    s_gi(s_account).tl(true, 'o', 'App1: {instance}: {link}'.supplant({
        'instance': jQuery('.app1 .app1-header').text(),
        'link': jLink.text()
    }));

    setTimeout(function() { window.location = jLink.attr('href'); }, 500);

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

The important piece isn't the jQuery pieces -- presumably, you have some method for identifying the links you're interested in tracking, and for implementing a delegated event handler -- but rather the last 3 statements.

- `setTimeout`

[This article by Adobe's Ben Gaines](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/custom-link-tracking-capturing-user-actions/) indicates (in the "using Link Track­ing on some­thing other than a link" section) that s.tl() introduces a 500ms delay before navigating. This is to ensure the asynchronous tracking call has time to execute before the page unloads. I've seen Chrome "cancel" HTTP calls that are ~simultaneous with navigation operations; Fiddler even erases the traffic from it's request list. I'm not experienced with WireShark, so I've decided to err on the cautious side and introduce the same delay.

- `event.preventDefault()`
- `return false`

This prevents the browser from reacting normally and navigating away immediately when the user clicks the link.

The crudity here seems to be the setTimeout. I'm a little uncomfortable about using a timer instead of something event-driven that takes as much or as little time to ensure the tracking call is made. However, without an officially supported from Omniture allowing for an explicit continuation or a custom tracking-captured event, this may be the safest thing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm definitely seeing s.tl requests failing in Chrome when you try to track clicks on links that take the user off page. It's very useful to know other people have experienced the same thing. They show up as "cancelled" in the network tab, and don't appear in a web proxy client at all.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that can stop live() is you. If you interrupt propagation at some point with Jquery's event.stopPropagation() or one of the browser specific methods, then sure, it'll die. But, otherwise you'll be fine.